# How to get SMAC3 working for Python 3x on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, bayesian

This is a great package for Bayesian optimization of hyperparameters (especially mixed integer/continuous/categorical...and has shown to be better than Spearmint in benchmarks).  However, clearly it is meant for Linux.  What do I do...?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download swig.exe (the whole package) and unzip it.  Then drop it somewhere and add the folder to path so that the installer for SMAC3 can call swig.exe.

Next, the Resource module is going to cause issues because that is only meant for Linux.  That is specifically used by Pynisher.  You'll need to comment out `import pynisher` in the `execute_func.py` module.  Then, set `use_pynisher:bool=False` in the `def __init__(self...)` in the same module.  The default is true.

Then, go down to the middle of the module where an `if self.use_pynisher....else` statement exists.  Obviously our code now enters the `else` part, but it is not setup correctly.  Change `result = self.ta(config, **obj_kwargs)` to `result = self.ta(list(config.get_dictionary().values()))`.  This part may need to be adjusted yet depending on what kind of inputs your function handles, but essentially you can see that this will enable the basic example shown in the included `branin_fmin.py` module.  If doing the random forest example, don't change at all...etc.